# How to check if no image is selected don't update?

Tags: php, pdo

I am currently working on a project with an update function using PDO the update function is working fine, but my problem is that when i try to update a record and stay it as is and when i see the database the image column is emplty..how can i check if the file is empty and when its empty do not update?because when i try to update a record with an image and hit the update button the image is gone..

**user.class.php**

```
public function upload($id,$FILE_NAME,$FILE_SIZE,$FILE_TYPE,$username,$password,$province)
{
if(empty($_FILE['myImage']['name'])){
echo "error";
}
else
{
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE tish_images SET  FILE_NAME=:FILE_NAME,FILE_SIZE=:FILE_SIZE,FILE_TYPE=:FILE_TYPE,username=:username,password=:password,province=:province WHERE id=:id");

$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $error )
{
    if ($error != UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
    {
        $errors[] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key] . ' was not uploaded.';
        //continue;
        return FALSE;
    }
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp  = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
    if($file_size > 2097152)
    {
        $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
        //continue;
        return FALSE;
    }

    try
    {
        $stmt->bindParam( ":id", $id);
        $stmt->bindParam( ":FILE_NAME", $file_name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindParam( ":FILE_SIZE", $file_size, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindParam( ":FILE_TYPE", $file_type, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindParam( ":username", $username);
        $stmt->bindParam( ":password", $password);
        $stmt->bindParam( ":province", $province);
        $stmt->execute();

        $desired_dir="image_uploads";

        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false)
        {
            mkdir($desired_dir, 0700);// Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_file($desired_dir.'/'.$file_name)==false)
        {
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$desired_dir.'/'.$file_name);
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {    //rename the file if another one exist
            $new_file=$desired_dir.'/'.$file_name.time();
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$new_file);  
            return TRUE;             
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
      echo $e->getMessage();
      return FALSE;
    }   
}
}
```

}

**update.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'DB.php';

$username = isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : '';
$password = isset($_GET['password']) ? $_GET['password'] : '';
$province = isset($_GET['province']) ? $_GET['province'] : '';
$FILE_NAME = isset($_GET['FILE_NAME']) ? $_GET['FILE_NAME'] : '';
$FILE_SIZE = isset($_GET['FILE_SIZE']) ? $_GET['FILE_SIZE'] : '';
$FILE_TYPE = isset($_GET['FILE_TYPE']) ? $_GET['FILE_TYPE'] : '';



if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
$id = $_GET['id'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$province = $_POST['province'];

if($crud->upload($id,$FILE_NAME,$FILE_SIZE,$FILE_TYPE,$username,$password,$province))
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully Updated!');</script>";
}
else
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Updating Failed!');</script>";
}

}
if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    extract($crud->getID($id));
    }
?>


         <?php echo $FILE_NAME; ?>
         <br />
         <br />
         <input type="file" name="files[]"  value="" multiple/>
         <br />
         <br />
         <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
         <br />
         <br />
         <input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo $password ?>">
         <br />
         <br />
         <input type="text" name="province" value="<?php echo $province ?>">
         <br />
         <input type="submit"/>
```

Comment: "how can i check if the file is empty " `$_FILE` and `empty()`

Comment: @Dagon what do you by that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're getting the image from a `<input type="file" />` tag and you want to check if an image was selected. You can try to use the `empty()` and `$_FILE` to check if an image was selected.

Example:

```
<?php
    if(empty($_FILE['myImage']['name'])):
        //don't update and display an error message.
    else:
        //update record.
    endif;
?>
```

*
*Note: If you want to only accept images you can easily do this with HTML `<input type="file" name="imagefilename" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" />`. Just don't forget to validate this in your PHP before you insert a new record or uploading the file selected to a directory.*

Comment: can you help me edit my code because i'm new with PDO?

Comment: Checking if an image is selected has nothing to do with PDO.

Comment: You shouln't dive straight into working with databses and all that stuff. Start out learning the basics first then go into more advanced stuff. Like every new language you learn, you first have to learn the basics.

Comment: But, can help me with this one first because i have trouble doing this..every time i update a record the image column in my database is always empty..

Comment: what if the user wants to update the column..that's where i'm having issue. so i think the best way is that to check if the file is empty then do not update and if the file have an image then update..

Comment: And the way you check if the user selected an image is the exact way I explained in the answer.

Comment: yeah i know that..and that what i'm looking for but my problem is that where do i need to put that in my code?

Comment: Where ever you're updating the table. Right before the update query.

Comment: if(empty($_FILE['myImage']['name'])): what is this "myImage" and "name"?

Comment: i updated my user.class.php but it says "insertion failed" and the page alwways says error..

Comment: Look I can't help you if you don't know the basics like I said. Plus you're using the `$_FILE` variable in your code and you don't even know what they are?!? Use google if you don't know what they are, that's my recommendation and learn the basics.

Comment: if(empty($_FILE['files']['name'])){

Comment: i already tried that but now it always says "successfully updated" even the file is empty

Comment: if(empty($_FILES['files']['name'])){
    echo "error";

Comment: but still when i try to leave the file as is the column in the database is empty